# Manipulating Compound Inequality

Tags: inequality

If $1>1-ab>0$, which of the following must be true?

1. $\frac ab >0$
2. $\frac ab <1$
3. $ab <1$

Option 1 and 3 are correct, but is option 2 necessarily correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. Take $a=1, b=0.5$. Then, $a/b=2>1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $0<1-ab<1$, then we have: $$0<ab<1.$$ This gives you 1 and 3, since if $ab>0$, then $a$ and $b$ must have the same sign. This therefore also implies that ${a}/{b}>0$.

To see that 2 is not always true, take $a=1, b=1/2$. Then: $$0<1-1/2=1/2<1,$$ but $\dfrac{a}{b}=2>1$.

Answer (score 0):

We are given that $1 > 1 - ab$ and $1 - ab > 0$, which is equivalent to 
$ab > 0$ and $ab < 1$, namely equivalent to $0 < ab < 1$. From this it is clear that options $1$ and $3$ are admissible. However, option $2$ is wrong, for the reason that if $a := 1/2$ and if $b := 1/3$ then $0 < ab = 1/6 < 1$ and $a/b = 2/3 > 1$.